# URL Redirection is not happening in IE11 after window.location.reload(true)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, internet-explorer-11, window.location

I am     making window.location.reload(true) call to server when ever the session gets expired . After clicking the button, call will be made to server for getting the details, but the URL is not getting changed on the browser and hence the same page is getting dislayed(timeout page) even after the user gets logged in successfully.This is happening only in IE 11 where as it is working correctly in Chrome etc..

```
 <a href="/" onclick="window.location.reload(true)">Restart Session</a>
```

This is working fine in chrome but not in IE(10 and above)

Answer (score 1):

test well:

```js
alert("page refresh")

function refresh() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload()
    }, 100);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="refresh" data-wrapper-class="custom-btn" data-corners="false" id="submit" onclick="refresh()">
```

Comment: Thanks !. But this does not solve my issue. still the url is not getting changed and hence the same timeout page is getting displayed